# How can I achieve one way sync in Couch DB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am using Couch DB as a master DB for data and at the client side I have installed Pouch DB instances. Now, I would like to sync data from master to clients, but no client should have permissions to sync data back to the server.

I know there is a one sided replication of db in Pouch/Couch Db but that doesn't restricts deliberate misuse of Couch db by unknown clients. (Any user can access my Couch DB instance's APIs and cause harm to it).

Note: there is no authentication system for the client.

Answer (score 1):

Consider validation functions on centralized CouchDB, described here: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions

> `validatefun(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx, secObj)`
>
> Throws: `forbidden` error to gracefully prevent document storing.
>   ...
>
> A design document may contain a function named `validate_doc_update`
>   which can be used to prevent invalid or unauthorized document update
>   requests from being stored.

Answer (score 0):

One crude way would be to put CouchDB behind a reverse proxy (nginx, for example) and configure the reverse proxy to block all `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` requests for the database.

Comment: That might work. But is there any cleaner solution to this?

Comment: You could use an update handler. This can prevent changes that happen via your application but it won't prevent someone from making changes to the DB on your server if they really want to. There's no 'native' way to do this (given that there's no authentication).